# AWT TextArea inside JTabbedPane visual bug

Tags: java, swing, textarea, awt, jtabbedpane

```
JTabbedPane main_tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane( JTabbedPane.TOP );
main_tabbedPane.setBorder( new EmptyBorder( 0, 0, 0, 0 ) );
main_tabbedPane.setBounds( 10, 76, 665, 473 );
main_tabbedPane.setVisible(false);

main_content.add( main_tabbedPane ); // main_content is a jpanel
```

I then call a class constructor which extends JPanel

```
alphaStarter_tab = new AlphaStarterPnl();
```

which among other things has a TextArea (from Java AWT not JTextArea)

```
public class AlphaStarterPnl extends JPanel {

 private TextArea outputTxtA;

 public AlphaStarterPnl(){

  outputTxtA = new TextArea("",4,50,TextArea.SCROLLBARS_VERTICAL_ONLY);
  outputTxtA.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 13));
  outputTxtA.setEditable(false);
  outputTxtA.setBackground(new Color(179,190,201));
  outputTxtA.setForeground(new Color(34,64,132));
  outputTxtA.setBounds(15, 133, 630, 300);
  add(outputTxtA);

 }
}
```

I then add this panel (which has alot more to it than the pasted code, but that doesn't matter here) to the tabbed pane

```
main_tabbedPane.addTab( "Copy Files", null, alphaStarter_tab, null );
```

When I do this, despite main_tabbedPane having been set to setvisible false, the TextArea pops up and not only that but it also appears in three places. (Perhaps appearing once at the 0,0 coordinates, then at the set x,0 coordinates then at the set x,y coordinates.  When I continue on in the program and this "flash of ugly content" goes away when a second tab is added.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Don't use a TextArea. Use JTextArea. Don't use setBounds(). Use a proper layout manager.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here can be that you are mixing lightweight components (i.e. Swing components like JTabbedPane, those with 'J' prefix) and heavyweight components (i.e. AWT components such as TextArea). Using these two types of components together can cause rendering issues.